# How to get from python reply and display it on browser?

Tags: jquery, python, get

I use a `.post()` to query for status of device in python function. When it is `done`, it should come back with the return value of the python function.

```
$.post('/request', {inputText: fbNum,key_pressed: fbType.toString()}).done(function (reply) {
      if (reply ^= "count") {
             $('#status_table tr #'+eachStatus).empty().append(the-reply-value-here);
      } });
```

part of my python file:

```
elif "C?" in response[0]:
         status="Count= %sH"%response[0].strip()[-2:] 
return status
```

How can i get and display the status?
Do i use `.get` in jquery? But i'm not sure of the format. Is it

```
$.get("/request", reply).done(function(data){
    $('#status_table tr #'+eachStatus).empty().append(the-reply-value-here);});
```

??

But the reply i will is something like `Count = FF`. what i want to display is only the `FF`. How should i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$.post('/request', {inputText: fbNum,key_pressed: fbType.toString()}).done(function (reply) {
    if (/^Count\s*=/.test(reply)) {
        $('#status_table tr #'+eachStatus).empty().append(reply.replace(/Count\s*=\s*/, ''));
    } 
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. +1 :) care to explain what `(/^Count\s*=/.test(reply))` means? and what about the `reply.replace()` part?

Comment: `/^Count\s*=/.test` is a regular expression which tests whether the reply starts with `Count =`, and then the [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function is used to replace the `Count = ` with an empty string you you could get the `FF` as the value

Comment: i see. where i can read more about that / \ ^ * . syntax? :s it's a bit confusing for me. so `/.test` is just a random name?

Comment: no [.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) is a function available in the regular expression object

Comment: You can read more about [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: oh!! thank you so much for this useful information! you saved my day again Arun :))